# What is wrong with my syntax? Livereload + Xampp + Chrome args = continued failure

Tags: json, google-chrome, livereload, same-origin-policy

Gahhh!  How do I get Livereload to stop giving this origin error? I get that normally security keeps you from calling files on your own machine, but I am trying to correct for that.  How?

1. Xampp servers are running.
2. Then this: open -a 'Google Chrome' --args -allow-file-access-from-files
3. This is in there:

   [image]
4. My HTML calls on it like so:

[image]

So why this error?

[image]

FWIW, I can call the file fine with Safari alone (which as you know will let you call files from your own machine.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this syntax worked:

```
d3.json("file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/d3/onedollar/onedollar3.json", function(error, root) {
```